# How can we represent P4mm space group?

Tags: symmetry, x-ray-crystallography

I understand that P4mm belongs to Tetragonal system. But how do we decide along which axis should we perform these symmetry operations?
According to my professor the axis along which we should do the operations is determined by which crystal system we are dealing with. **According to him, for tetragonal system we should perfom the 4 fold rotation along the c axis, and the fist mirror operation along a and b axis, and the second mirror operation along the diagonal connecting a and b.**
This is the representation they have shown for P4mm space group.
[image]

when I tried to do it, after the first mirror operation itself  I got this particular configuration. **So what is the need of the second mirror operation given that we should only write unique symmetry operations.**

Comment: Well, there are clearly two mirror planes, so you need to mirror twice.

Comment: yup...actually the second mirror plane is only along the a axes.